# manage_page permissions for facebook page using test user

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am working on an application which will allow users to post stuff to their fb pages.

**1) I created an app on facebook using a developer account.**

**2) I created test user with permissions to manage_pages and publish_page actions**

 **3) I tried accessing the page access token using the PHP sdk but I am not able to access it.**
**4) The page is public on which I am trying to get data.Eventually I also want to post, but I only get the page_id and page name.**

```
   Route :: get('fbpage',function(){

   $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => env('FACEBOOK_APP_ID'),
  'app_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'),
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
  'access_token' => $_SESSION['fb_access_token']
  ]);


  $response = $fb->get('/{page-id}',$_SESSION['fb_access_token']);
```

// Get the response typed as a GraphPage

```
 $page = $response->getGraphPage();
 $accessToken = $page->getAccessToken($_SESSION['fb_access_token']);
 echo $accessToken;
 dd($page);
```

**Response**

```
GraphPage {#369 ▼
#items: array:2 [▼
"name" => "page-name"
"id" => "54576557031120"
 ]
}
```

What are the things I am missing to get the entire page data with page access token?

Comment: Are you talking about an actual test user here? Is that user actually an admin of the page in question? (The page must have been created by the test user, I think – you can not make a test user the admin of a real page.)

Comment: good catch, did not even think about that. i added it as a side note to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It´s called "Declarative Fields", you need to specify the fields you want to get or you will only get id and name:

```
$fb->get('/{page-id}?fields=name,access_token',$_SESSION['fb_access_token']);
```

It was introduced with v2.4 of the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

**Side Note: Of course you have to be admin of the Page. You can only get a Page Token if you are admin.**

Comment: doesn't the getAccessToken method explicitly do the same? I should atleast get the page token with it right?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphNode/5.0.0#page-instance-methods > "Only available in the /me/accounts context"

Comment: honestly, i am not sure how that works, i don´t like to put too much control into the hands of the sdk - those functions are more likely to change than a simple api call. just use my suggestion and remove those 2 lines with the access token and the echo.

Comment: I tried using the request suggested by you,but I am still not getting the page access token. The access_token in the declarative fields is the page access token I believe.The response is as below  The access token I get is the user access token I use from session

Comment: yes, that would be the page token. make sure you are using a user token with manage_pages and publish_actions (manage_pages is the most important one to get a page token).

Comment: `FacebookResponse {
  #httpStatusCode: 200
  #headers: array:14 [▶]
  #body: "{"name":"{page}","id":"id"}"
  #decodedBody: array:2 [▼
    "name" => "{page}"
    "id" => "id"
  ]
  #request: FacebookRequest {#366 
    #app: FacebookApp {#359 
      #id: "{id}"
      #secret: "{secret}"
    }
    #accessToken: "fb_access_token"
    #method: "GET"
    #endpoint: "/{page-name}?fields=name%2Caccess_token"
    #headers: array:1 [▼
      "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ]
    #params: []
    #files: []
    #eTag: null
    #graphVersion: "v2.5"
  }
  #thrownException: null
}`

Comment: if you don´t get the token, it´s most likely a problem with the user token. debug it and make sure it includes manage_pages: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: I want to confirm can I give the manage_pages in the test user and test app scenario? I have already given but does not seem to work.If you could point me to some tutorial it would be great.

Comment: all permissions work without review for users with a role in the app. just try in the api explorer, select your app and the permissions you want: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: **Scopes user_birthday, user_likes, user_friends, email, manage_pages, pages_show_list, publish_actions, public_profile**
I tested the access token and the scope seems to be fine

Comment: is the user admin of the page? (see my edited side note)

Comment: Yes I created a test user and then a page using that user.So he is the admin.If I get the `me` scenario right I beleive the user token should belong to the admin, right?

Comment: yes. did you also try with your own (real) account and a real page you own? also, try the exact same api call in the api explorer.

Comment: Yes I just tried it with my personal account and a page created by me,still same result,I do not get the page data.Is a long lived token mandatory? I dont see that generated for the test app.

Comment: no, you do not need an extended token. try with a simple call to me/accounts in the api explorer. is the page listed and does it include a token?

Comment: i will update the thread after testing the possibilities.Thank you for the inputs